# How to set page number in footer to start from a specified number using epplus

Tags: c#, footer, epplus

I need to set the starting page no for an excel file generated using c# epplus library. I was able to set the footer as follows.

```
ws.HeaderFooter.OddFooter.RightAlignedText =string.Format("Page-{0}", ExcelHeaderFooter.PageNumber);
```

I need to set the page number to start from a custom number input like no 9. How can I do that?
Example: page number in first sheet number should be 9 then 10 in the second sheet then 11, etc...

Comment: what do you mean by "starting page no"?

Comment: Like start the page no with 9 then continue 10,11,12 etc. in the proceeding pages

Comment: you want to format the footer for all the pages starting from the nth page?

Comment: Yes, set the starting page no to 9, then continue to rest of the pages, 2nd page as 10, 3rd page as 11, ect

Answer (score 2):

`ExcelHeaderFooter.PageNumber` is a string which's value is "&P", it is interpreted by excel as page number, so you can not update it from code.

However, you can achieve what you need using:

```
var sheetNumber = 1;
var startingPageNumber = 9;
foreach (var sheet in package.Workbook.Worksheets)
  {
    sheet.HeaderFooter.OddFooter.RightAlignedText= string.Format("Page-{0}", sheetNumber + startingPageNumber);
    sheet.HeaderFooter.EvenFooter.RightAlignedText = string.Format("Page-{0}", sheetNumber + startingPageNumber);
    sheetNumber++;
  }
```

The above code is tested and verified to do what you need.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, but in my case there is a one sheet and multiple pages using the page break. I'll check weather I can have the each page in the worksheet, then apply the logic mentioned by you.

Answer (score 2):

In the Header/Footer's of Excel, you have the following codes:

> `&D`      Current date
>
> `&T`      Current time
>
> `&F`      Workbook name
>
> `&A`      Worksheet name (from the worksheet tab)
>
> `&P`      Current page number
>
> `&P+x`        Current page number plus x
>
> `&P-x`        Current page number minus x
>
> `&N`      Total pages in the workbook
>
> `&&`      Ampersand character

Like the [Yahya says in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48422176/5213794), `ExcelHeaderFooter.PageNumber` has the `&P` value, so, you can just use `&P+x`

```
int PageStart = 5;
worksheet.HeaderFooter.OddFooter.RightAlignedText = string.Format("Page-{0}+{1}.", ExcelHeaderFooter.PageNumber,PageStart-1);
```

It will just work.

Please, note that without the dot the example didn't work, in that case, excel just concat the 1 and 5 (i really dont know why that happen)